# C# and the CSV file

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, csv

I formatted this data using c#, streamreader and writer and created this csv file.   Here is the sample data:

```
A------B-C---D----------E------------F------G------H-------I

NEW,  C,A123 ,08/24/2011,08/24/2011 ,100.00,100.00,X123456,276135

NEW,  C,A125 ,08/24/2011,08/24/2011 ,200.00,100.00,X123456,276135

NEW,  C,A127 ,08/24/2011,08/24/2011 , 50.00,100.00,X123456,276135

NEW,  T,A122 ,08/24/2011,08/24/2011 ,  5.00,100.00,X225511,276136

NEW,  T,A124 ,08/24/2011,08/24/2011 , 10.00,100.00,X225511,276136

NEW,  T,A133 ,08/24/2011,08/24/2011 ,500.00,100.00,X444556,276137

I would like the following output:

NEW,  C,A123 ,08/24/2011,08/24/2011 ,100.00,100.00,X123456,276135

NEW,  C,A125 ,08/24/2011,08/24/2011 ,200.00,100.00,X123456,276135

NEW,  C,A127 ,08/24/2011,08/24/2011 , 50.00,100.00,X123456,276135

NEW,  C,A001 ,08/24/2011,08/24/2011 ,350.00,100.00,X123456,276135

NEW,  T,A122 ,08/24/2011,08/24/2011 ,  5.00,100.00,X225511,276136

NEW,  T,A124 ,08/24/2011,08/24/2011 , 10.00,100.00,X225511,276136

NEW,  T,A001 ,08/24/2011,08/24/2011 , 15.00,100.00,X225511,276136

NEW,  T,A133 ,08/24/2011,08/24/2011 ,500.00,100.00,X444556,276137

NEW,  T,A001 ,08/24/2011,08/24/2011 ,500.00,100.00,X225511,276137
```

With each change in field "I", I would like to add a line, sum column F, add a "A001" to C, and copy the contents of the other fields into that newly ADDed line.

The letters on the columns are for illustrative purposes only.   There are no headers.

First, what should I do first?   How do I sum column F, copy contents of all fields, and add "A001" to C?   How do I add a line and copy the fields w/ each change in I?

Comment: The **C** in CSV means "Comma", and you have no commas there.

Comment: Also, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: I left the commas out for clarity.  Faux pas.

Comment: Seriously, you think it's clearer to have a CSV with no commas?

Comment: No. Seriously, can you help me with the questions?  Or point me in a constructive direction.

Comment: @Ondrej: Please, *please*, don't update 2 year old questions. It totally messes up the ordering of relevant questions. In fact, why are we even bothering to update 2-year old questions? It's unnecessary work that leads to unnecessary static on the radars of active posters!!!

Comment: @code4life These days new posts are reviewed by many people and they have quite a good quality. But some old posts are terrible and I am just trying to improve them a little bit. Furthermore, I usually update questions where there is no accepted answer so that an asker gets a reminder. I didn't know that it causes problems.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek: I can appreciate what you're doing - it's good work. But this post is so old, and because it got updated, it ends up taking precedence over more recent and more relevant posts - and this is something SO needs to fix, so not your fault. I guess it's really an issue of needing updated but old posts show up a bit lower in the order of priority of the newer and more relevant posts. Sorry for taking you to task, but I'm starting to get frustrated by seeing so many old posts pop up.

Answer (score 0):

From your questions it doesn't sound like your data fits a flat file format very well, or at least not a CSV (analogy to a single DB table).  Wanting to 'copy the contents of the other fields into that newly ADDed line' implies to me that there is possibily a relationship that might be better expressed referentially rather than copying the data to a new row.

Also keep in mind the requirement to sum according to column 'F' suggests that you will need to iterate over every row in order to calculate the sum.

If you decide to go a route other than a CSV your might try a light weight database solution such as [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).  An alternative might be to look at [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) or [DataContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx) (with Serializer) and just work with objects in your code.  The objects can the be serialized to the disk when you're done with them.

Comment: Thanks, Ken.  Its not a lot of rows, that vary from 1 to 150.  I'll look into the database solutions you stated.

Comment: This file will be uploaded into another application that is why it needs to be in csv format.  I know I can iterate through the lines, but how do I program c# when the value changes in column I?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom iterator block, just as an example this is showing how to add the new line that contains your "A001" C column. You can just as easily add a new sum column - keep in mind though that you should keep the number of columns in each row the same.

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetUpdatedLines(string fileName)
{
    int? lastValue = null;
    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(fileName))
    {
        var values = line.Split(',');
        int myIValue = Convert.ToInt32(values[7]);
        if (lastValue.HasValue && myIValue != lastValue)
        {
            //emit new line sum
            values[2] = "A001";
            yield return string.Join(",", values);
        }
        lastValue = myIValue;
        yield return line;
    }
}
```

Comment: The number of columns for each row are the same and will not change.  I'll try this 'custom iterator block.'  Thanks, BrokenGlass.